# How to detect crypto mining?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to make a Nagios plugin which can detect crypto miners.

The problem is if the miner is single threaded and running on a multi core host, then the load avg will be below 1, which isn't by definition a problem.

Also I would like the plugin to handle hosts with different numbers or CPU's.

**Question**

If a host is running a miner (single or multi threaded) will I then always detect it if I say: crypto miner detected if the 3 load avg from `uptime` are almost the same?

That way I don't have to worry about number or CPU's. Correct?

Comment: Load average is unlikely to *ever* go below zero. I would expect any mining software to max out the CPU as much as possible. I'd just monitor for unusual load - set a threshold 20% higher than "normal" use and adjust over time.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ups. That should have been "below 1". Now fixed. thanks.

Comment: With that fixed, I'd figure out what your 95th percentile is for CPU, and set an alarm if that's exceeded consistently for, say, an hour, or 24 hours, or something along those lines. Again, I doubt there are many single-threaded miners that don't max out every CPU they can get their hands on...

Comment: "Miners" are just clients that connect to crypto networks... Why don't you just firewall those networks off?

Comment: Basically, instead of focusing on catching the program checking hashes (which you'll struggle to do accurately and there are ways to still run a crypto miner undetected if all you check is load... which you should already have a nagios check for load averages anyway).

Comment: In order to actually use the miner on your host, the attacker would need to exfil any successful hashes. Lock down your boxes firewalls with `iptables` or `nftables` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If your cryptominer can be detected with a 100% usage on a single core you can use

```
mpstat -P ALL
```

And check if on %user column

```
mpstat -P ALL | awk ' { print $3 " " $4 } ' | grep -E "^[0-9]"
```

exist a single core that is near 100% continuously, I think that this can be done with a single awk line

Comment: You are checking the first digit to see if it is between 0 and 9?

Comment: Yes, I check the first digit is a cpu core number. You can extract the most busy CPU with

mpstat -P ALL | awk ' /^.{11} +[0-9]+/ { print $4 } ' | sort -nr | head -n1

Comment: A multi-threaded miner that uses all available CPU cores, lets say thats 12 but i set them as nice 10 and cpulimit of 0-5% would not be discovered by such means.

Comment: Correct. But limiting the cpu ends with a low profitability malware.

Comment: You can bundle lets say 100.000 malware machines together to solve the same block of X, or you can bundle your 100.000 malware machines together and than bundle these into a crypto group and together solve X, than split X up between the members of the group where you already "own" 100.000 machines.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this tread is for programming and other higher level operations that I know nothing about

BuuuuT;

As someone with experience with crypto miners running on company hardware (E.G. I work at a family business and have been semi-allowed to run crypto miners) I can only offer the knowledge I have for myself.

IDS is not stopping me. We are running a Cisco Meraki MX67 with the AMP and IDS/IPS and I tested with all Blocked Website Categories, full lists, not top sites, and I am still getting through.

TLS and SSL on public ports (80, 443, etc)

my other option was to just use a VPN, which would be far less likely, as it is very noticeable. Even with split tunnelling, there would be settings on the local device to find.

**The best bet is to log traffic, and look for outliers; crypto miners will always contact the servers listed in it's configuration.**

Also crypto mining on CPU would stress the L2/L3 cache.

re-reading OP, web based attacks are tough, I am not sure how they work; but there would be a consistent connection made to a static server.

[here is a link to](https://xmr.omine.org/web_miner.html) a pool based web mining script meant to be implemented on a webpage; to run on a persons computer when they visit the site. It is old a defunct, but it may help give you some insight into how they function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good answers here that may work in some cases, but they all assume the same thing: That you'd like to detect the presence of a miner after it's already running.

This would generally be best accomplished with a heuristic scanner and a library of hashes for detecting already-known applications. I'm not aware of the existence of such a project, but it may be an integrated function in some kind of security suite / malware scanner. However, if a malicious application of any kind is already running then you're very late to the game.

All of that aside, a more reasonable (and easier) approach here would be to keep that miner from getting onto your machine at all. Depending on what kind of avenue you're expecting these miners to come in via and what these systems do, you should lock down access to your systems to prevent this from happening. It generally shouldn't be permissible in any way that a user can install and subsequently execute a functional program of any kind unless that's exactly what they are supposed to be doing with a given resource.

While the above describes a methodology, it does not describe exactly how to mitigate this sort of thing. There are answers to that, but they'll be entirely dependent on your implementation beyond the most generic of recommendations.

For example, the `audit` daemon or `rkhunter` can be a good way to determine if anything "foreign" is running and who/what put it there. `selinux` provides a solid way to keep unapproved files from being executed in a context they should not. A good imaging/deployment system can help to allow graceful "nuking from orbit" and establish guarantees for a consistently "clean" system. Good security practices and scrappy deployment models make most of the worries regarding detecting threats irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Most miner attacks that I have seen exploit a web application vulnerability such as Drupal's Drupalgeddon vulnerability, and subsequently add an entry to crontab to download the miner at certain intervals.

So surprisingly a good option might be to monitor your crontab file. This has the added benefit of detecting other similar attacks as well.

You can use the file monitoring plugin https://www.nagios.com/solutions/file-monitoring/ for example, to monitor the file size of `/etc/crontab` or whatever crontab file your web user (ie drupal or www-data) has access to.

Sidenote:

In addition you can install the nagiosgraph plugin http://nagiosgraph.sourceforge.net/ and manually review the graphs to identify spikes in CPU Load.

Answer (score -1):

This comes down to awareness of your infrastructure, something 95% of all companies do not have.

First thing is that i would setup a monitoring system that will monitor CPU usage and process count, create a baseline for what is normal, what is yearly peaks and so on.

Monitor active processes. Together with my documentation and baseline i would decide what is normal and what is not. Example, if the server is a Tomcat server, i would expect to see processes that handles the Tomcat service itself, Java, HTTP-Requests, backup and so on. But if a rogue process suddenly appear i havn't seen before or the active process count suddenly jumps by 16, 32 or something in that regard, outside of peak and stays their, i can determine that it is not a normal process or processes for the operation of the server and i can investigate.

Havign a Intrusion Detection System in place is also critical, for a process to get initiated it needs to ask for CPU time in one way or another. The IDS system can monitor this, log it, and again if i see anything outside the norm i can investigate.

Based on the crypto "service" it might not ram up the CPU very high on the server, since you can throttle processes or spread it out over 32 cores or what ever your server is capable of. So i would monitor multiple things and from that determine what is going on.

In this regard i would say their is no direct way to determine this, unless you target a specific crypto miner.

Comment: If you downvote than have the courage to say why.

Comment: Likely because you're making assertions that in the context of this question are less than helpful. The OP asked how to detect crypto mining, and you jumped in with essentially: "You should look at all of your infrastructure for a YEAR first". OP wants to know what criteria can be used to detect this, but you're giving generic advice on how to monitor infrastructure. It's not that you're giving bad or technically incorrect advice, but OP is already using Nagios so they're probably already doing at least most of this while the question at hand is going largely unanswered.

Comment: Gosh, that reads like I'm bashing you: I'm not. I'm only suggesting that a more narrow answer would be appropriate here.

Comment: @Spooler you cannot detect crypto mining by just "well well, i see my CPU is at 100%" unless it was written by a amateur. Why would you create something, go through the trouble to find vulnerable servers to just get detected within 5 minutes. Their is no straight answer to such a question.